# Why does the action button in iOS 5 default to "Open In iBooks"?

Tags: pdf, ios5

My iPhone app has been set up to accept PDF's. In previous versions of the OS, when viewing a PDF (in Mail, for example) you could tap the action button and the top button on the action sheet would default to whichever app you last used to open a PDF.  Now in iOS 5 I've noticed that it defaults to iBooks, no matter what.  You must select `Open In ...` and then tap your desired app if you don't wish to use iBooks.  If I delete iBooks from my iPhone, then the action button reverts to the previous behavior of defaulting to the app last used.  When re-installing iBooks, the bias towards iBooks returns.

Is this universal across iOS 5 users and devices? Is this a bug or a feature? Can you think of a workaround?